# Dyadic reindexing

Tags: matlab, indexing, dct

I need to change the order of column indices, in this fashion:

```
J = 8;
N = 3;

ind = [2:2:J, fliplr(1:2:J)];
x = randn(J, N);
y = x(ind, :);
```

This is required for a fast DCT implementation. Is there a faster/more elegent way to implement this in Matlab? I found functions like `dyaddown` and `dyadup` with a similar behaviour but they only give one half or double the vector size.

Comment: This seems to be a little faster: `ind = [2:2:J, J-1:-2:1];`. I'm assuming `J` even